# SQL Server 2016 Service Account Issue

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2016. It has been working fine for several days.  This morning after an unexpected reboot I noticed one of my applications was not working.  I noticed the SQL Server service was not running.  I tried starting it and I received a "*the service did not start due to a logon failure*"  I noticed the service is set up to logon as *NT Service\MSSQLSERVER* and the password is populated.  Why and how would this password be changed and different from when I installed SQL a few days ago?  How do I properly resolve this issue?  I tried resolving the issue using this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282254/sql-server-service-does-not-start-successfully-because-of-a-logon-fail) but I find it to be somewhat confusing.

Comment: My guess would be file system corruption. The password for virtual accounts aren't manageable, but you should be able to change it to local system, then back to NT Service\MSSQLSERVER with no password.

Comment: The GUI always shows a password whether there is one or not, I don't think that's your problem.  Perhaps the "Log on as a service" local security policy is misconfigured?  Check the Security log and see if it gives you a more specific error code.